# How can access to RSUs in TraCIDemo11p?

Tags: omnet++, veins

i want to send a Request for the shortest path from nodes to RSUs, but i dont know how to access to my RSUs in TraCIDemo11p? Coordination of RSUs exist in omnet.ini with these names, rsu[0],rsu[1],...
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

How to send messages from a car and how to receive messages at an RSU is demonstrated by the sample simulation of Veins 4.4: here, a car sends up to one message as soon as it stops. Other cars and RSUs react to a received message by re-broadcasting it (if they haven't yet).

Answer (score 0):

By accessing you mean how a message reaches to a particular destination (particular node or RSU)? For that you may access any node (including RSU) by putting an identity field (string type or int) into the wsm message. Once a broadcasted beacon message is received by node or an RSU then it can simply check for the recipient.
TraCIDemo11p and TraCIDemoRSU11p are the modules you use to put any programming logic suits your need.